How to run a template based on update to a directory in azure pipeline
I want to conditionally run a template within azure pipeline based on it the commit has updated a particular directory. When i run the expression it's always see the variable as false. What am I missing?

        - stage: Provision_Central_Techops
      dependsOn: [] 
      
      displayName: Provision Central Techops
      jobs:
      
      - job: Provision_TechOps_Central_Stack
        displayName: Provision TechOps Central Stack
        variables:
          workingDirectory: terraform/stacks/techops
       
        steps:
        - bash: |
            
                  echo workingDirectory $(workingDirectory)
                  
                  if git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD | grep -q $(workingDirectory); then
    
                    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=techopsUpdated]true"
                    
                  else
    
                    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=techopsUpdated]false"
                    
                  fi
                  
                    
          name: Check_For_Update
        
        - ${{ if eq(variables.techopsUpdated, true) }}:
          - template: steps/terraform.yml
           
            parameters:
              environment: prod
              workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
              stackName: techops
              terraformVersion: $(terraformVersion)
        - ${{ else }}:
          - script: echo "techopsUpdated $(techopsUpdated)"

I have tried adding a condition still no joy. The condition is comparing again a null value

- stage: Provision_Central_Techops
  dependsOn: [] 
  
  displayName: Provision Central Techops
  jobs:
  
  - job: Provision_TechOps_Central_Stack1
    displayName: Provision TechOps Central Stack
    variables:
      workingDirectory: terraform/stacks/techops
    
   
    steps:
    - bash: |
        
              echo workingDirectory $(workingDirectory)
              
              if git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD | grep -q $(workingDirectory); then

                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=techopsUpdated; isOutput=true]true"
                
              else

                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=techopsUpdated; isOutput=true]false"
                
              fi
              
                
      name: Check_For_Update
  
  - job: Provision_TechOps_Central_Stack
    
    condition: eq(variables.techopsUpdated , true)
    displayName: Provision TechOps Central Stack
    variables:
      workingDirectory: terraform/stacks/techops
   
    steps:

    
    - template: steps/terraform.yml       
      parameters:
          environment: prod
          workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
          stackName: techops
          terraformVersion: $(terraformVersion)


Ensure that variables are set with isOutput=true if they need to be used in subsequent steps.
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=techopsUpdated;isOutput=true]true"


Got the same after updating @Bright Ran-MSFT has a point

@NicholasNamacha, You did not set the job to dependsOn on the previous job. See the YAML sample in my answer and do not miss any thing.

In your initial code sample you're using a single job, but in the second code sample you're trying to use the condition in another job. My sample pipeline would work for the initial scenario (use the output variable in the same job). If that's not the case, and as I mentioned in my answer, the syntax of referencing output variables with dependencies varies depending on the circumstances.

The template expression "${{ xxx }}" is evaluated at compile-time before runtime, while the variable techopsUpdated is created at runtime. This could cause the expression "${{ xxx }}" always evaluates the value of this variable as empty, so the condition will always return false.

EDIT:
As a workaround, you can do like as below:

Within the same stage, you can add another job before
job 'Provision_TechOps_Central_Stack' to run the step 'Check_For_Update'.

In the step 'Check_For_Update', set the variable 'techopsUpdated' as a output variable.

On the job 'Provision_TechOps_Central_Stack', set it dependsOn the previous job. And use the condition key on this job check the value of the output variable.


stages:
- stage: Provision_Central_Techops
  jobs:
  - job: checkUpdate
    variables:
      workingDirectory: terraform/stacks/techops
    steps:
    - bash: |
        echo workingDirectory $(workingDirectory)
        if git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD | grep -q $(workingDirectory); then
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=techopsUpdated;isoutput=true]true"
        else
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=techopsUpdated;isoutput=true]false"
        fi
      name: Check_For_Update
  
    - bash: |
        echo "techopsUpdated $(Check_For_Update.techopsUpdated)"
      displayName: 'Show value of techopsUpdated'

  - job: Provision_TechOps_Central_Stack
    displayName: 'Provision TechOps Central Stack'
    dependsOn: checkUpdate
    condition: eq(dependencies.checkUpdate.outputs['Check_For_Update.techopsUpdated'], 'true')
    variables:
      workingDirectory: terraform/stacks/techops
    steps:
    - template: steps/terraform.yml
      parameters:
        . . .

With above configurations, if the value of output variable 'techopsUpdated' is 'true', the job 'Provision_TechOps_Central_Stack' gets run, otherwise it gets skipped.
Related documentations:

Use output variables from tasks
Pipeline conditions



That makes sense, what other options are availables?

@NicholasNamacha, I shared a workaround in my above answer. See EDIT.

Output variables are created at runtime, so you should use conditions instead of template expressions.
Example pipeline:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  - name: techopsUpdated
    value: 'false'  # <----------- change value to test conditions

jobs:
  - job: Provision_TechOps_Central_Stack
    displayName: Provision TechOps Central Stack
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - bash: |
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=techopsUpdated]${{ variables.techopsUpdated }}"
      name: Check_For_Update
    - script: |
        echo "techopsUpdated: $(techopsUpdated)"
      displayName: 'techopsUpdated: true'
      condition: eq(variables['techopsUpdated'], 'true')
    - script: |
        echo "techopsUpdated: $(techopsUpdated)"
      displayName: 'techopsUpdated: false'
      condition: eq(variables['techopsUpdated'], 'false')

Running the pipeline:

Please note that the syntax of referencing output variables with dependencies varies depending on the circumstances (e.g. using a regular job or a deployment job, same job vs different job/stage, etc) - see the Dependency syntax overview for more details.
